# Searching by extensions in specific Dir C++

Tags: c++, windows

In specific directory i need to find all files with some specific extension (for example .log)
and than save it somewhere. In need only c++ solutions cause i'm trying it on win 2003 server and c++ is my restrictions. Thank you very munch

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate all of the files in a directory using [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and don't forget to call [`FindClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) when you're done).  You can pass in a filter to these functions to only look for certain filenames, e.g. `directory\*.log`.

As you enumerate the files, the [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure that gets returned tells you the filename and attributes of each file (among other things).  For each file, check the file attributes to make sure it's a regular file by checking that it has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` flag so that you ignore directories.

For example:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fileInfo;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\directory\\to\\search\\*.log", &fileInfo);
if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    ;  // handle error
else
{
    do
    {
        if(fileInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
        {
            printf("Found a .log file: %s\n", fileInfo.cFileName);
        }
    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fileInfo));
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        ;  // handle error
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: The find functions allow one to specify a mask/filter, so you don't even need to check the extension, just pass "*.log" to FindFirstFile

Comment: @Necrolis: Good point, I've updated my answer and added sample code.